# Asp.net C# EMail Address with Special Character

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, encoding, special-characters

i am sending emails with the integrated System.Net.Mail

i do like

```
MailAddress abs = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("my@email.com", "Web Präsenz", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

when the E-Mail comes to Client the "ä" character is missing. seems like some encoding Problems.

anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried Unicode encoding (i.e. UTF-16)?

Comment: ok ill tryy. but you think its needed? though utf-8 seems enough for all characters

Comment: Does your (unnamed) client understand UTF-8 as well?

Comment: Well UTF-8 seems to be standard for e-mails, but it's still worth trying out. Perhaps UTF-8 is the right encoding and you just need to specify different parameters (construct a new UTF8Encoding and use that).

Comment: its outlook version not know though. its customers pc. utf-8 also unicode do not make it.

Comment: Also note this issue for which there is an issue with non-ASCII characters in the email addresses in the MailMessage class support.microsoft.com/kb/2576045

Answer (score 4):

try adding these too:

```
message.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

It may also be a mail server issue.  Try sending it to various e-mail address; POP3, WebMail, etc.

There some more info here, though you've probably already looked here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I just spent 5 hours debugging a similar problem, and the solution I found may be the solution to this problem also. Since no one has posted any other solutions I will contribute my findings.

There seem to be a subtle bug in the .NET2.0 Mail API which causes encoding of Recipient names in the mail headers to fail. This occurs if the To property (and possibly others) of the MailMessage instance is accessed before the message is sent.

The following example will cause the To header to be sent without encoding, causing at least my mail client to display the name as "??????...":

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("address@example.com", "ÆØÅ Unicode Name"));
message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "Body";
Console.WriteLine(message.To[0]);
smtpClient.Send(message);
```

However moving the WriteLine below the send line, causes the To header to be correctly encoded:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(new MailAddress("address@example.com", "ÆØÅ Unicode Name"));
message.Subject = "Subject";
message.Body = "Body";
smtpClient.Send(message);
Console.WriteLine(message.To[0]);
```

I assume this bug will occur on the Cc and Bcc properties as well, so beware of this. 
Hope anyone finds this useful.